# Move a node and its child to another node at same level

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to move a node along with its child element to the immediate next node at same level.

The DSPACCNAME node and its child element should get moved to DSPACCINFO Node.

Below is my input XML

```
<ENVELOPE>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 1</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
 <DSPACCINFO>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA>-100.14</DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA></DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA></DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA>-100.14</DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 2</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
 <DSPACCINFO>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA></DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-470.00</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>470.00</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA></DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 3</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
 <DSPACCINFO>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA>-942.00</DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-445.05</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>446.00</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA>941.00</DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 4</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
 <DSPACCINFO>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA></DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-830.99</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>830.99</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA></DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Below is the XSL I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="DSPACCNAME">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::DSPACCNAME)]|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="DSPACCNAME"/>-->
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not getting the expected output with the above XSL

My expected output is as below

```
<ENVELOPE>
 <DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 1</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA>-100.14</DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA></DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA></DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA>-100.14</DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 2</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA></DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-470.00</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>470.00</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA></DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 3</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA>-942.00</DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-445.05</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>446.00</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA>941.00</DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCINFO>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Account 4</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPOPAMT>
   <DSPOPAMTA></DSPOPAMTA>
</DSPOPAMT>
  <DSPDRAMT>
   <DSPDRAMTA>-830.99</DSPDRAMTA>
</DSPDRAMT>
  <DSPCRAMT>
   <DSPCRAMTA>830.99</DSPCRAMTA>
</DSPCRAMT>
  <DSPCLAMT>
   <DSPCLAMTA></DSPCLAMTA>
</DSPCLAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ENVELOPE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DSPACCINFO"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DSPACCINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::DSPACCNAME[1]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I tried with preceding-sibling too but without suffixing it with "[1]" for which it produced the result properly for first set alone.  For the second set onwards it created an element for all the preceding nodes of DSPACCNAME.  Can you elaborate the the significance of suffixing it with "[1]", so that I understand it.

Comment: `preceding-sibling::DSPACCNAME[1]` selects only the first DSPACCNAME sibling (in reverse document order). If you remove the `[1]` predicate, it will select all DSPACCNAME siblings before the current node. With your XML structure, that would mean that each DSPACCINFO element would copy all preceding DSPACCNAME siblings, each time increasing the count by 1.